# How do i tell a cell to contain the sum of a entire row in excel

Tags: excel, row, sum

I would like to tell an excel sheet to put, for each row, the sum of the values between B and G cells in the H cell.

For exemple:
`H1 must contain the SUM(B1:G1)`,
`H2 must contain SUM(B2:G2)`
...

I want to make this process automatic instead of specifying on each H cell that is the SUM of the corresponding values between B and G.

Thanks.

Comment: Althoug it has the smell of a SuperUser question, this can be solved using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double-click the little black box in the bottom-right hand corner of the cell, excel will automatically replicate the contents of that cell to the bottom of your current list revelant to the cell references within the cell.  You can also click-and-drag the little black box to specify the range yourself

Comment: AutoFill gets a bit cumbersome after, say, 10,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This block will fill the entire acvitvated sheet when ran.

```
Sub FillSums
   Dim I as Integer
   I=0

   While Err.Description = ""
       I=I+1

       Application.ActiveSheet.Range("H" & I).Formula = "=SUM(B" & I & ":G" & I & ")"
   Wend
End Sub    

Dim I as Integer
```